# NIB loading fails unless UIView subclass declared @objc(ClassName)

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit, nib

We have a number of `UIView` subclasses that we load from NIBs. Here's an example of one:

```
@objc(SwimlaneCell)
public class SwimlaneCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    …
}
```

I wondered if the `@objc(SwimlaneCell)` declaration on the front was necessary; I'm pretty sure I've worked on Swift projects with `UIView` subclasses loaded from NIBs before, and this has not been required.

However, when I try to entirely remove the `@objc(SwimlandCell)`, or reduce it to just `@objc` (with the class name omitted), then loading the class from a NIB fails. The error is:

> Thread 1: "[<UIView 0x7ffbe10b0fd0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key collectionView."

In this case the `UIView` mentioned is the `SwimlaneCell` above.  `collectionView` is the property it has that's being injected during loading from a NIB – but here is not being found by the key value mechanisms.

#### Possibly relevant details:

- This specific cell has had the NIB registered with a  `UITableView` and is being loaded as a consequence of a call to `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`.
- `SwimlaneCell` is contained in a Swift package along with the table it is used in. The actual app uses the package.

#### Questions

- Is this always needed and have I imagined not requiring this before?
- If it's not always needed, why might it be needed in this project and what can I do so it is not needed?

Comment: Is this UIView class for sure an instance of SwimlaneCell class when this error appears? It looks like it did not load this view as SwimlaneCell class but as a generic UIView class. If this class is in external package then perhaps you did not set the "Module" field in interface builder and you only set the "Class" field in the "Custom Class" inspector view?

Comment: `@IBOutlet private weak var ...` vs `@IBOutlet weak var ...`